# VB.NET Get Response header

Tags: vb.net, header, request

So, I want to get a "Location" header from response using

```
System.Net.HttpWebResponse
```

. How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.headers.aspx#Y100

```
Dim myHttpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
myHttpWebResponse.Headers("Server");
```

Comment: I tried that, but I don't know how to get response index by his name.

Comment: Since its a the Headers property is WebHeaderCollection class which is implementation of NamedValueCollection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx, you can get items by name. Updated the answer to show that.

Comment: Ok that function is ok, but that not solves my problem. The Charles 3.5.1 shows me : http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/8782/asddopl.jpg, but when i check out headers on VB.NET Program - there's no "Location" header

Comment: I am not 100% sure about your case but seems like the problem is this location header is returned on redirection and you are not looking at the right redirection response header. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses & http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/httpwebrequest_response.aspx

Comment: @TETYYS And please accept the answer if it meets the requirements for the above question.